# Winter Bash 2020

Tags: discusión, winterbash, winterbash-2020

El "Winter Bash 2020" ha comenzado y los sombreros (y las máscaras) se enumeran a continuación.

Sólo hay dos respuestas: una para los sombreros secretos y otra para los sombreros normales. La lista de los sombreros secretos se actualizará a medida que los descubramos.

Winter Bash es un evento divertido, así que los detonantes de los sombreros secretos deben ser puestos entre spoilers (usa el marcador `>!`) para no arruinar la diversión de aquellos usuarios que quieran descubrir los detonantes por sí mismos.

<sub>Traducción libre de [Winter Bash 2020 hat list 👒 🎩](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357915/)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

## Sombreros normales para el Winter Bash 2020

#### Distanciamiento Social (Principal)

[image: Distanciamiento Social (Principal)]

Visita cualquier pregunta en cualquier sitio principal (incluyendo Meta Stack Exchange). Las visitas mediante las aplicaciones móviles, y las visitas a las paginas de etiquetas (p.ej. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) también cuentan.

---

#### Distanciamiento Social (Meta)

[image: Distanciamiento Social (Meta)]

Visita cualquier pregunta en cualquier sitio meta (incluyendo Meta Stack Exchange). Las visitas mediante las aplicaciones móviles, y las visitas a las paginas de etiquetas (p.ej. https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/discussion) también cuentan.

---

#### TikTop

[image: TikTop]

Haz una pregunta que sea respondida rapidamente

---

#### Plataforma

[image: Plataforma]

Comienza una discusión en Meta

---

#### Edward

[image: Edward]

Haz una pregunta recibida positivamente en 5 días diferentes (obteniendo la medalla Curioso)

---

#### Hanafuda

[image: Hanafuda]

5 publicaciones con un marcador positivo

---

#### Backlog

[image: Backlog]

Responde una pregunta antigua sin respuestas

---

#### Snaphat

[image: Snaphat]

Responde en 30 minutos, +3 y aceptada

---

#### Cazador de Reputación

[image: Cazador de Reputación]

10 respuestas en 1 día con marcador positivo

---

#### Kitsune

[image: Kitsune]

Vota para reabrir y contesta una pregunta

---

#### Quiero Suscribirme

[image: I Wish to Subscribe]

Vota positivamente 3 solicitudes de nuevas características(feature requests) en MSE

---

#### Bûche de Noël

[image: Bûche de Noël]

Pregunta, responde o vota el 25 de Diciembre

---

#### Dónde en el mundo?

[image: Dónde en el mundo?]

Publica o vota el 21 de Diciembre

---

#### Dónde en el mundo?

[image: Dónde en el mundo?]

Publica o vota el 21 de Diciembre

---

#### Feliz Año Nuevo

[image: Feliz Año Nuevo]

Chatea el 1 de Enero

---

#### Milliner

[image: Milliner]

Colecciona 11 sombreros

---

#### Bravucón

[image: Bravucón]

3 revisiones de votos de cierre exitosas

---

#### Portero

[image: Portero]

3 revisiones de votos de reapertura exitosas

---

#### Limpiador de Chimeneas

[image: Limpiador de Chimeneas]

3 revisiones de ediciones sugeridas exitosas

---

#### Wa-boushi

[image: Wa-boushi]

Gana la medalla Gurú

---

#### Carmen

[image: Carmen]

Sugerencia de edición aprobada

---

#### Dame Espacio

[image: Dame Espacio]

Únete a una nueva comunidad

---

#### Linterna

[image: Linterna]

Prueba el Modo Oscuro

---

#### Subiendo Rosas

[image: Subiendo Rosas]

Haz una pregunta de +5 con 5 respuestas

---

#### Matryoshka

[image: Matryoshka]

10 votos de cierre o reapertura exitosos

---

Answer (score 2):

## Sombreros Secretos para el Winter Bash 2020

**Nota: por favor *no* editar un detonante a no ser que un empleado confirme que es correcto.**

---

#### Vexilólogo

[image]

> Levantar un reporte útil en cualquier sitio

---

#### Samovar

[image]

---

#### Pelo de Cuarentena

[image]

> Lleva un sombrero en cualquier sitio

---

#### Toma Esto!

[image]

> Haz el tour y obtén la medalla Informado

---

#### Impúlsate a ti Mismo

[image]

> Obtén otros 3 sombreros secretos en un sitio. *(Sombrero y detonante de 2018)*

---

#### Cordovan

[image]

---

#### Balalaika

[image]

---

#### Discípulo

[image]

---

#### Calurosa Bienvenida

[image]

> Vota positivamente la primera publicación de cualquier usuario. (Sombrero y detonante de 2014)

---

#### Mariachi

[image]

---

#### Movin' on Up

[image]

---

#### Give a Leg Up

[image]

---

#### This is Fine

[image]

---

#### Lámpara de aceite

[image]

---

#### Derecho a correr rápido y saltar de alegría

No es un sombrero per se, pero el detonante de esto no se revela. Necesitas haberte ganado este "derecho" (y estar registrado en el sitio de Winter Bash) para poder acceder al "juego" en ese sitio.

Comment: Haz el tour and obtén la medalla Informado -  Hice el tour AND no tengo mi cabrona espada.... btw: se te paso el and Pikoh

Comment: En las secretas, falta Cruse of Oil (¿vasija de aceite? ¿aceitera?)

Comment: gracias @padaleiana,añadido

Comment: no se podrá *tejer* ?:(